# Internal Temp Arduino

Tags: c

Summary: Internal temp having trouble connecting to the right channel.
Want to get right value from the channel.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

uint8_t ReADC()//read value ad
{
  ADMUX = (1 << MUX3) | (1 << REFS0) | (1 << REFS1) | (1 << ADLAR);
  //single conversion 
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN) | (1<<ADSC) | (1 << ADPS2);

  ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){
    ADC();
  }
  void SPI_MASTER(){
    DDRB = (1 << PB0) | (1 << PB3) | (1 << PB5);
    SPCR = (1 << CPOL) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR0) | (1 << SPI2X) | (1 << SPE); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, does the 64-128 map to temperature?

Comment: What about `21.8    Temperature Measurement` in `https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf`? Guys, why don't your read the docs first?

Comment: Yes, Sections 21.7 (ADC Conversion Result) and 21.8 (Temperature Measurement) of the datasheet do have the information necessary to convert the ADC temperature value into degrees C. I'm sorry I don't have an Atmega328-based Arduino to write and try a solution on.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with comments — you should read DS, ADC Conversion Result and Temperature Measurement sections.

But there is a bug in measurement process (ADC usage issue) that prevent you from reading right ADC result for temperature calculation.

See:

```
uint8_t ReadADC()
{
    ADMUX = (1 << MUX3) | (1 << REFS0) | (1 << REFS1) | (1 << ADLAR); // (1)
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN) | (1<<ADSC) | (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1)
              | (1 << ADPS0) | (1 << ADIE);

    while( ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC) );
    return ADC;                                                       // (2)
}
```

You (1) select `ADLAR`, so ADC result is shifted toward high bit of 16-bit `ADCH:ADCL` pair. But then (2) you read the 16-bit value and convert it into 8-bit value by throwing out high 8 bits. As a result, you get two least significant bits of ADC result in two most significant bits of returned value. So, these bits can encode 0, 64, 128, 192 only.

```
uint8_t SPI_transmit_data()
{
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);
    SPDR = ADC;                              // (2)
    while(!SPSR & (1<<SPIF));

    PORTB |= (1 << PB0);
    return(SPDR);
}
```

The same is here, the lowest 8 bits of ADC result is writed into 8-bit `SPDR` and higher 8 bits are thrown out.

Use `ADCH` instead of `ADC`